# Read on pipe being blocked when child(writer) is put on sleep on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, process, pipe, fork

In the following code I'm trying to make the child send some string and then make it sleep for a while. Everytime the child sleeps for some reason the read of the parent gets blocked. The read works fine if the sleep is removed but it is essential for the application I'm making.

```
import os

nameout, namein = os.pipe()
cpid = os.fork()

if cpid == 0: #                    Child Process
    os.close(nameout)
    namein = os.fdopen(namein,'w')

    namein.write("Empire of the Clouds")
    print("I've just written")
    os.system('sleep 60') # Removing this makes everything work

else: #                            Parent process
    print("I'm inside parent")
    os.close(namein)
    songname = os.fdopen(nameout)
    print("I'm going to read")
    songAndNum = songname.read()
    print("Song name read")
    print(songAndNum)
```

Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong or offer some other alternative. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the sleep command is still burning CPU cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here. Firstly the string probably has not really been written into the pipe when the child goes to sleep.  The string is probably still sitting in an internal buffer.  To fix, call `namein.flush()` after `namein.write()`.

Secondly, `songname.read()` will block until a large amount of data is collected from the pipe or until the pipe gets closed as a side effect of the child process exiting.  To fix, change `songname.read()` to `songname.readline()` and in the child write a newline `\n` after the title string before calling `flush()`.